# Validar números telefónicos de celulares de Costa Rica

Tags: html, formularios, regex, validación, condiciones

Necesito por favor la expresión regular para números de teléfono celular en Costa Rica. Las restricciones serían:

- Los números se componen de ocho dígitos
- Puede o no tener un guión después de 4 dígitos Ej. ####-#### o ########
- No existe ningún número celular que comience con números de 0-4 Ej. (5-9)###-#### o (5-9)#######

Agradecería muchísimo la ayuda

Comment: y tienes algo del código cual es el error???

Comment: Lee [ask], trata de agregar que has hecho pues de lo contrario tu pregunta quedará cerrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar:

```
^[5-9]\d{3}-?\d{4}$
```

- `[5-9]`: un número entre 5 y 9
- `\d{3}`: tres números
- `-?`: un guión opcional
- `\d{4}`: cuatro números

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4WvTu/1)

Comment: @Glorfindel Muchísimas gracias! La verdad no me he familiarizado mucho con expresiones regulares, pero prometo que haré mi tarea cuando me enfrente de nuevo a este reto. Por cierto, la restricción del primer número era del 5 hasta el 8, disculpas por el "dedazo" y de nuevo, gracias